# ReadOnly columns in External List: SharePoint 2013.

Tags: 2013, external-content-type, external-list, read-only, external-data-column

I want to make some fields **ReadOnly** in **External List** in SharePoint 2013. I have tried JavaScript and SPUtility approaches as guided in [this blog](http://www.enjoysharepoint.com/Articles/Details/make-column-or-field-readonly-in-sharepoint-2013-list-21063.aspx), but unfortunately did not work. In SharePoint Designer, the columns are not visible in EditForm.aspx page and I cannot do any customization to the columns.  Kindly help me guide with the right approach as I am stuck in this for several days. FYI, I don't have access to Central Admin and I don't have Visual Studio Environment for SharePoint.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to make some fields Read Only for an External List. The idea is to create a new Edit Form in SharePoint Designer. The original EditForm.aspx file does not show tables and columns in it. Once you create a new EditForm.aspx file, Edit it in Advanced Mode. You can see all the table structure, columns, labels etc. in XSLT Format. Find attribute, `ControlMode="Edit"` with `ControlMode="Display"` for those columns you want to make ReadOnly.